# How do I handle transitioning a mobile user to a desktop experience?

Tags: navigation, mobile-web, responsive-design

My team and I are making iterative changes to a site, slowly converting it to a responsive site. During this transition there may be some instances where a mobile user (who is on a responsive page) may want to hop on over to a page that is desktop-only for now.

Are there are any example of handling this behavior in the wild? Do you have any suggestions?

One options that I have been thinking about: Using an icon next to the link to indicate the experience they will receive. Another, less desirable option would be to omit those links altogether.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to warn the user of the change in UX when one of these links are accessed, rather than marking each link with a note. You can provide them with a choice of whether or not to continue to the desktop-only page after displaying something along the lines of,

> This section has not been optimize for mobile experience. Are you sure you want to continue?

Or, if it is preferable to not ask for user validation, you can simply show a redirect prompt,

> Redirecting to site's full version in 3... 2... 1...

This way the user is aware of the decision.